# PS2 keyboard interface state issue

Tags: vhdl

I have to make a project at the university which is an interface for a PS2 keyboard using a FPGA board (nexys2). I am writing the code in VHDL and the issue i have is that somewhere in the control component, where the packets of 11 bits are sent, the process gets stuck in GETBYTE3 state when i press a key instead of going in START state after all the bits are received properly and shifted into the FIFO register, it runs through different state  and never gets into START properly. But when i reset it manually, by switching the CLR to 1 after each press of any key on the keyboard, it works fine.

The way this system is the following: when the scan code is recieved, it is shifted into a FIFO memory from which, in another component, is decoded and displayed on the 7 segment display.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity ps2_src is
Port ( PS2C : in STD_LOGIC;
       PS2D : in STD_LOGIC;
       CLR : in STD_LOGIC;
          FIFO : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
          scan : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
          deb : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end ps2_src;
architecture Behavioral of ps2_src is
type STATE_TYPE is (START, WCLKLO1, GETBYTE1, WCLKLO2, GETBYTE2, CHECK,     WCLKLO3, GETBYTE3);
signal state: STATE_TYPE := START;
signal tfifo: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 downto 0) := X"11111111";
begin
control: process(CLR, PS2C)
     variable keyv1_temp, keyv2_temp, keyv3_temp: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto     0);
     variable shift1, shift2, shift3: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(10 downto 0);
     variable parity: STD_LOGIC;
     variable bit_cnt: NATURAL := 0;
     begin
    if CLR = '1' then
        state <= START;
        bit_cnt := 0;
    elsif   PS2C'EVENT and PS2C = '0' then
        case state is
                when START => 

                    if PS2D = '0' then
                        state <= START;
                    else
                        state <= WCLKLO1;
                    end if;
                    deb <= "00000000";

            when WCLKLO1 =>                      
                    shift1 := PS2D & shift1(10 downto 1);                           
                    bit_cnt := bit_cnt + 1;

                    if (bit_cnt = 11) then      
                        state <= GETBYTE1;
                    end if;
                    deb <= "00000010";

            when GETBYTE1 =>
                    keyv1_temp := shift1(8 downto 1);

                    parity := keyv1_temp(0) xor keyv1_temp(1) xor keyv1_temp(2) xor keyv1_temp(3) xor keyv1_temp(4) xor keyv1_temp(5) xor keyv1_temp(6) xor keyv1_temp(7);

                    bit_cnt := 0;
                    state <= WCLKLO2;
                    deb <= "00000100";

            when WCLKLO2 => 
                    shift2 := PS2D & shift2(10 downto 1);                           
                    bit_cnt := bit_cnt + 1;

                    if (bit_cnt = 11) then      
                        state <= GETBYTE2;
                    end if;
                    deb <= "00001000";

            when GETBYTE2 =>
                    keyv2_temp := shift2(8 downto 1);                               

                    bit_cnt := 0;
                    state <= CHECK;

                    scan <= keyv2_temp;
                    deb <= "00010000";

            when CHECK => 

                    if keyv2_temp = X"F8" then
                        deb <= "00100000";
                        state <= WCLKLO3;
                        tfifo <= tfifo(23 downto 0) & keyv1_temp;
                    else
                        if keyv1_temp = X"E0" then
                            deb <= "01000000";
                            state <= WCLKLO1;
                            tfifo <= tfifo(23 downto 0) & keyv2_temp;                   
                        else
                            deb <= "10000000";
                            state <= WCLKLO2;
                            tfifo <= tfifo(23 downto 0) & keyv1_temp;
                        end if;
                    end if;

            when WCLKLO3 => 
                    shift3 := PS2D & shift2(10 downto 1);                                                        
                    bit_cnt := bit_cnt + 1;

                    if (bit_cnt = 11) then      
                        state <= GETBYTE3;
                    end if;
                    deb <= "11000000";

            when GETBYTE3 =>                                                                                        keyv3_temp := shift3(8 downto 1);

                    bit_cnt := 0;
                    state <= START;
                    deb <= "10100000";

        end case;
    end if;
end process control;
FIFO <= tfifo;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I would personally not use the PS2 clock directly as clock input for your logic. Instead sample it to the higher MHz domain (e.q. 50 MHz). FPGA's are made for high-speed switching, so for low-speed signaling the edges might not align as you expect.

Comment: Next: try do do this without using variables: they don't always synthesize the way you'd expect. Signals are the way to go for synthesis. Do you have a test bench to test your code?

Comment: Yes, i have made a top-level which i am using for tests

Comment: So you say that instead of using the PS2 clock in the sensitivity list, i should use, for example, the clock from the board?

Comment: yes, that is often the adviced way. Also, you could consider implementing a [picoBlaze](https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/picoblaze.html) to handle the PS2. This could be simpler and smaller. But you'll have to look around for examples (I cannot find any anymore) maybe @paebbels knows.

Comment: Also consider [this VHDL example of a PS2 keyboard interface](https://github.com/theshadowx/keyboard-ip). Apparently the input needs to be filtered.

Comment: Okay, so i found what the problem actually is..
In the state check, a clock received from the PS/2 Keyboard is used, and that ruins the state machine..
The problem is that i don`t really have an idea how could i get the CHECK state to work independent from the PS2 clock..

Comment: actually, like I said: it's better not to use the PS/2 clock directly. But that requires a redesign of your system. I'm not going to do that for you.

Comment: Okay, I will try..thank you